# ansible replace module idempotency

Tags: ansible

I'm attempting to add a line into a file at multiple spots. This is my code for this which is working. However, this is not idempotent, as I end up getting multiple `output_limit = 1000` lines in my file. What am I doing that is causing this, and what is the best method to make this idempotent?

```yaml
- name: Add output_limit for each runner
  ansible.builtin.replace:
    path: /opt/gitlab_config.toml
    regexp: 'id(.*)\n(?!token)(.*)'
    replace: id\1\n  output_limit = 1000\n\2
```

Here is a truncated version of the file I'm modifying:

```ini
concurrent = 8
check_interval = 0
shutdown_timeout = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "run-05"
  url = "https://servername"
  id = 349
  token = something

[[runners]]
  name = "run-06"
  url = "https://servername"
  id = 350
  token = something

[[runners]]
  name = "run-07"
  url = "https://servername"
  id = 351
  token = something

[[runners]]
  name = "run-08"
  url = "https://servername"
  id = 352
  output_limit = 10000
  token = something
```

Comment: changing the regex from `regexp: 'id(.*)\n(?!token)(.*)'` to `regexp: "(^.*id.*\n)(?!output_limit.*)(^.*token.*)"` corrected my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I tried both your regexes, and even with the second one this seems to be incorrect because of the current `replace` value - it duplicates the `id` and breaks the formatting. It could be partially fixed by setting `replace` to `\1  output_limit = 1000\n\2`, but if you then change the regex without cleaning up the file, you will end up with a broken config and duplicated lines. Moreover, some IDEs automatically remove the indents on code cleanup from TOML files, so hardcoding a fixed number of whitespaces might not be a working solution.

To sum up - it would be hard to achieve idempotency with regexes.

Since Ansible doesn't have a dedicated module to edit TOML files and [`ini_file`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/ini_file_module.html) cannot handle TOML properly as INI and TOML are different formats, a better (and much more scalable) solution would be to generate this file from a [template](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_templating.html) instead of editing:

```yaml
# playbook.yaml
---
- name: Add a line into a file at multiple spots
  hosts: gitlab_runners
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: Generate the config file
      template:
        src: templates/gitlab_config.toml.j2
        dest: opt/gitlab_config.toml # NOTE: I changed path for testing
#        validate: "you-can-also-run-a-validation-command-and-pass-the-path-to-the-config-file %s"
      delegate_to: localhost # Use `delegate_to` if you generate the config locally
      run_once: true # and `run_once` to only generate the local config once
```

```ini
# templates/gitlab_config.toml.j2

concurrent = {{ concurrent | default(8) }}
check_interval = {{ check_interval | default(0) }}
shutdown_timeout = {{ shutdown_timeout | default(0) }}

[session_server]
  session_timeout = {{ session_timeout | default(1800) }}

{% for runner in groups['gitlab_runners'] %}
[[runners]]
  name = "{{ hostvars[runner].inventory_hostname }}"
  url = "{{ hostvars[runner].url }}"
  # id = {{ hostvars[runner].id | default("should be generated automatically") }}
  token = "{{ hostvars[runner].token }}"

{% endfor %}
```

This example also uses the concept of Ansible [inventory](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiQ9aW2wOmEAxU6QvEDHbLJCIoQFnoECAYQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.ansible.com%2Fansible%2Flatest%2Finventory_guide%2Fintro_inventory.html), where you define the variables per host or per group of hosts. This will allow you to have equal parameters for an unlimited number of runners, but also define custom one for some of them if you need:

```yaml
# inventory.yaml
---
all:
  vars:
    ansible_python_interpreter: auto_silent
    ansible_connection: local
  hosts:
    localhost:
gitlab_runners:
  vars:
    concurrent: 8
    check_interval: 0
    shutdown_timeout: 0
    output_limit: 1000
    url: https://servername-{{ inventory_hostname }} # just an example
  hosts:
    run-0[5:7]:
      token: something
    run-08:
      output_limit: 10000
      token: something
```

To use it, just add `--inventory inventory.yaml` to your command.

Of course, auth tokens should not be stored in plain text, so you can encrypt them using [Ansible Vault](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/vault_guide/index.html) (I used `123` so you can check):

```
ansible-vault encrypt_string TOKEN351
New Vault password: 
Confirm New Vault password: 
Encryption successful
!vault |
          $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
          61646166316333613663313430373564363639316132323330636135313664356335326131643431
          3036386165303638633831373535646439363633373364640a366436336436333634333039376234
          61326433313531323833643834653236313161373036393038653735366265646630653062623437
          3339626433626561380a356366653833353235653731316532333166623732336163303838343766
          6462
```

This would result into an inventory like below. This example also contains the original ID, so if you uncomment the `id` in the template, you can keep them:

```yaml
# inventory.secure.yaml
---
all:
  vars:
    ansible_python_interpreter: auto_silent
    ansible_connection: local
  hosts:
    localhost:
gitlab_runners:
  vars:
    concurrent: 8
    check_interval: 0
    shutdown_timeout: 0
    output_limit: 1000
    url: https://servername-{{ inventory_hostname }} # just an example
  hosts:
    run-05:
      id: 349
      token: !vault |
        $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
        61626465326563656538373438376135383334383636373031393965373534633933363866656566
        3863626231323265386435353837656137346534373139300a323265396537643065303963363138
        38363865626336666661643532633662393537376635343064366232326336343738373165313932
        3536323639663034310a633565386130396537316637353566356332646332633132663634653431
        3831
    run-06:
      id: 350
      token: !vault |
        $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
        64333564343261383665633063373462333834323435333530306335656230323330373334366232
        6165346635366465663561353639343565613436353637310a356562343634653234306531366662
        31393037353636383239373736303363383734623635343932376665336566393436633866303364
        6130366337666662310a363133346632653264306437613632303136323636346262356234393438
        3561
    run-07:
      id: 351
      token: !vault |
        $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
        66376532373862633862343362626635323461636536333061626336323331383136326338623963
        6634623266653765643936373430316263376536343865380a326633336134613861323037373862
        30343236393139613931393334343334306261666633373937633464376434333131336235663664
        3832383362643037390a663161623539363533653635343766663761326161363162623561313864
        6633
    run-08:
      id: 352
      output_limit: 10000
      token: !vault |
        $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
        38393265653133616331303431363638633366656638633165623863653336303434333164353361
        3261663733316164363639336130383164383734396334300a396163646334316561666539363263
        36666266383338393437373731366162303030613236323036373436376463393631316331333865
        3031376533326630640a643765386266646634623361666262383735663034663235363161306431
        3430
```

The execution command would be like this (Ansible Vault also allows other options, please check the docs):

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yaml --inventory inventory.secure.yaml --ask-vault-pass
```

With the following execution result:

```ini
concurrent = 8
check_interval = 0
shutdown_timeout = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "run-05"
  url = "https://servername-run-05"
  id = 349
  token = "TOKEN349"
  output_limit = 1000

[[runners]]
  name = "run-06"
  url = "https://servername-run-06"
  id = 350
  token = "TOKEN350"
  output_limit = 1000

[[runners]]
  name = "run-07"
  url = "https://servername-run-07"
  id = 351
  token = "TOKEN351"
  output_limit = 1000

[[runners]]
  name = "run-08"
  url = "https://servername-run-08"
  id = 352
  token = "TOKEN352"
  output_limit = 10000
```

This would also put a good start for an overall adoption of configuration-as-code approach to set up your runners.

Comment: I visited the idea of using a template for this and would be ideal, and I completely agree that this should be configuration-as-code. However, I noticed that the gitlab-runner token in the config.toml file ends up being different that the one we use when registering the runner, we are using a docker-in-docker runner configuration, which might be a reason behind that. I also believe the way we register a runner is changing in an upcoming release of gitlab too which might change this as well.